# Select EVERY department and number of employees with salary higher than 10000

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need to select every department name and number of employees earning 10000 or more. That's my code.

```
SELECT d.department_name, COUNT(e.employee_id) 
FROM hr.employees e
JOIN hr.departments d ON d.department_id=e.department_id WHERE e.salary > 10000
GROUP BY d.department_name;
```

It shows only departments which contains employees earning 10000 but I also need rest of departments with number 0 or - in column COUNT(e.employee_id). Can you help me?

Comment: What is your expected output? Do share with some sample data.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT d.department_name, COUNT(e.employee_id) FROM hr.employees e
JOIN hr.departments d ON d.department_id=e.department_id WHERE d.department_id in
(SELECT distinct e.department_id from employees  e WHERE e.salary > 10000)
GROUP BY d.department_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional aggregation. The idea is to not put the condition on employee salary in the `join`, but instead it in a conditional `sum`:

```
select
    d.department_name,
    sum(case when e.salary > 10000 then 1 else 0 end) cnt_high_salaries
from hr.department d
inner join hr.employee e on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.department_id, d.department_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need  `outer join` in your original query.

```
SELECT d.department_name, 
       COUNT(e.employee_id) 
  FROM hr.departments d 
LEFT JOIN hr.employees e
   ON d.department_id=e.department_id
  and e.salary > 10000
GROUP BY d.department_name;
```